# How to find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{n}{1000}}{\sqrt{n+\frac{n}{1000}}+\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Hey please i need some small tips to get me starting. I tried multiplying with the conjugate but it didnt bring me very far..

Comment: Lol it doesn't even converge

Comment: What does your question mean?

Comment: @mathJuan He wants to know how to evaluate the infinite limit.

Comment: im sorry i wanted to know why the limit goes to infinity

Comment: The limit doesn't go anywhere. The terms go somewhere though. If the problem is to show the limit is $\infty,$ why didn't you say so in your question?

Comment: $$\frac{\frac{n}{1000}}{\sqrt{n+\frac{n}{1000}}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{n\frac{1}{1000}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{1000}}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\frac{1}{1000}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{1000}}+\sqrt{1}}=c\sqrt{n}$$

Comment: @ Did: Yes, I wait a solution for your last question.

Comment: @mathJuan Which last question? (Unrelated: No space between @ and username, please.)

Comment: @Did Thank you. I want to say about the question "why didn't you say so in your question?" .

Comment: @mathJuan User zhw. asked this, not I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the limit, note that $\sqrt{n + \frac{n}{1000}} + \sqrt{n} \leq \sqrt{4n} + \sqrt{n} = 3\sqrt{n}$. Thus $$\frac{\frac{n}{1000}}
{\sqrt{n + \frac{n}{1000}} + \sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{\frac{n}{1000}}{3\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{3000}\sqrt{n}$$ which goes to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: excuse me where did the n at the end go ?

Comment: $n/\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: oh yeah ahahh thanks

Comment: shouldnt it be sqrt(n)/3000 ?

Comment: Ahh yes, you're correct. However, the constant does not change the limit behavior of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Set $c=\sqrt{1001/1000}$; then you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1000(c+1)}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1000(c+1)}=\infty
$$
This is because
$$
\sqrt{n+\frac{n}{1000}}=\sqrt{\frac{1001}{1000}n}=c\sqrt{n}
$$
Thus you have
$$
\frac{\dfrac{n}{1000}}{c\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}}=
\frac{1}{1000(c+1)}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}
$$